# Is this logarithmic inequality true?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, logarithms

Assume we have two complex variables $h_i$ and $h_d$ which satisfy the following relationship

$$ 2\ |h_i|^2\leq \ |h_d|^2$$

can we say that 
$$\log\left( 1+ \frac{\big||h_d| - h_i\big|^2}{2}\right) \leq\log\left(1+(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^2 \frac{|h_d|^2}{2}\right)? $$

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logarithm is an increasing function, so your inequality is equivalent to
$$\big||h_d|-h_i\big|^2\le |h_d|^2(1+1/\sqrt2)^2$$
But
$$\big||h_d|-h_i\big|\le |h_d|+|h_i|\le |h_d|(1+1/\sqrt2)$$
So the inequality follows.

Comment: Thank you very much, can you please explain How you obtained this $$\big||h_d|-h_i\big|^2\le |h_d|^2(1+1/\sqrt2)^2\iff \big|1-|h_i|/|h_d|\big|\le 1+1/\sqrt2$$? I understand everything else after this step...

Comment: @Henry Remove the squares (can do, as every squared thing is nonnegative) and then divide both sides by $|h_d|$.

Comment: if i divide by $|h_d|$ i get $|1- \frac{hi}{|hd|}|$..

Comment: @Henry Right, a mistake happened :) corrected.

Comment: thanks, in general can i say that $\big||h_d|-h_i\big| \leq |h_d|+|h_i|$? what about:$\big||h_d|-h_i\big| \leq |h_d|-|h_i|$?

Comment: @Henry I've simplified it a bit.

Comment: Thank you very much, is it the same case for :$\big||h_d|-h_i\big| \leq |h_d|-|h_i|$?

Comment: @Henry That's not true, consider $h_d=1$, $h_i=-1$. I used triangle inequality, in full it should be written as $||h_d|-h_i|=||h_d|+(-h_i)|\le||h_d||+|{-}h_i|=|h_d|+|h_i|$.